# How to get metadata xml for SAML IdP initiated SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I need to get metadata xml for my SSO IdP initiated. How can I get or create it?
I am using LightSaml.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used this page
https://www.samltool.com/idp_metadata.php

Be careful with data you put here to generate XML Metadata, check twice if there are the same as in SAMLResponse (and SAMLRequest if you are using SSO SP Initiated). It may cause configuration errors.